# dynamic link with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

During my searching on this topic, I would like to have some help.

In my web page, I would like to build a HREF link that redirects in a precise web page depends to the current month.

My link is :

```
<td><a href="/comptes/mon_compte.html?display=affilies_periode&id=${vendeur.id}&  month=javascript:monthNumber">Détails pour le mois en cours</a></td>
```

And my code in JS :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    date1 = new Date();
    document.write("<p>date1</p>");
    monthNumber = date1.getMonth();
    document.write("<p>monthNumber</p>");
</script>
```

with the result of month, I would like to make the query dynamic like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/comptes/mon_compte.html?display=affilies_periode&id=2&***month=javascript:monthNumber***
```

Please, could you give me a piece of advice?

Ale.

Comment: You want to make a dynamic link?

Answer (score 12):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="myUniqueLinkId">name of link</a>
```

**JS**

```
var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
var myURL = 'http://domain.tld/myLocalFile.php?month=' + month + '&param=1';
document.getElementById('myUniqueLinkId').href = myURL;
```

Or alternatively just handle it completely at runtime:

```
<a onclick="window.location='http://domain.tld/myLocalFile.php?month=' 
   + (new Date()).getMonth();return false;" href="#">name of link</a>
```

Best solution is still to handle this not in JS but in your serverside code and just generate the correct links there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just a question about #, what's the meaningful of <a href="#" here?

Comment: An anchor is required to have a filled `href` attribute by HTML standards, to validate successfully. Since `#` only points to the top of the current page and can never cause navigation `href="#"` is the generally accepted *"this link will never work regularly"* notation. In the first example it's overridden by JS, in the second it's bypassed in favor of the `onclick`.